# Return an object from a library?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to return an an object from a library?

For example, in the `data.js` it will contain

```
return {
  "name": "Testing"
}
```

In `index.js` I like to do something like this:

`const data = require('./data.js');`

`console.log(data.name)`

Comment: Modules don't `return` anything, they *export* things.

Comment: Notice that node.js support importing JSON files, so maybe you don't need any JS code in `data.json` at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the following in `data.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "testing"
};
```

That way it will be visible in `index.js` through the `require()` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the return, ie. the file is in json format, that would also work.

```
{
  "name": "Testing"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `module.exports` like so:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "Testing"
}
```

And then import it with `require`:

```
const data = require("./data.js");
```

If you only want to import the value of `name`:

```
const { name } = require("./data.js");
```

You could also use `import/export` like so:

```
export const data = {
    name: "Testing"
}
```

`index.js`:

```
import data from "data.js";
```

If you only want to import the value of name:

```
import { name } from "data.js";
```